# Passing javascript variables to php file on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I read and tried the solutions that I found but it do not working for me.
I have form used to book events, and I what to pass some of it data to php file used to send SMS message to the user with some info.

On the javascript I have this code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function

    // old form action is #em-booking
    $(".em-booking-form").attr('action','send-samir.php');
    $(".em-booking-form").submit(function( event ) {
        // show/hide messages.
        $('#messageBeforeSubmit').removeClass('showMessage').addClass('hideMessge');//remove message
        $('#messageAfterSubmit').removeClass('hideMessge').addClass('showMessage');//show message
        $('#orderBeforeSubmit').removeClass('showMessage').addClass('hideMessge');//remove messge


        var get_training = $('#training').text();
        var get_date = $('#date').text();
        var get_time = $('#time').text();
        var get_phone = $('#dbem_phone').val();

        var dataString = 'training='+escape(get_training)+'&date='+escape(get_date)+'&time='+escape(get_time)+'&phone='+escape(get_phone);




        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'send-samir.php',
            data: {
                'phone': get_phone, 
                'training': get_training, 
                'date': get_date, 
                'time': get_time
            }
        });

    });
});
```

I tried everything that mark as comment but none work for me,
the JavaScript takes the values I want, I check it with the alert

On the PHP file I have this code:

```
<?php       
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $training = $_POST['training'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $time = $_POST['time'];

    $message .= $training;
    $message .= "\r\n";
    $message .= "\r\n";
    $message .= "date: ";
    $message .= $date;
    $message .= "\r\n";
    $message .= "\r\n";
    $message .= "time: ";
    $message .= $time;
    $message .= "\r\n";
    $message .= "\r\n";
    $message .= "Thank you";
    $message .= "\r\n";

    send_sms($message, $phone); 
    echo "ok";
?>
<?php
    function send_sms($msg, $recepients)
    {
        $msg = str_replace('<', '%26lt;', $msg); // "Cleans" the message from unsafe notes
        $msg = str_replace('>', '%26gt;', $msg); // "Cleans" the message from unsafe notes
        $msg = str_replace('\"', '%26quot;', $msg); // "Cleans" the message from unsafe notes
        $msg = str_replace("\'", '%26apos;', $msg); // "Cleans" the message from unsafe notes
        $msg = str_replace("&", '%26amp;', $msg); // "Cleans" the message from unsafe notes
        $msg = str_replace("\r\n", '%0D%0A', $msg); // "Cleans" the message from enter
        $message_text = $msg;
        $sms_host = "api.inforu.co.il"; // Application server's URL;
        $sms_port = 80; // Application server's PORT;
        $sms_path = "/SendMessageXml.ashx"; // Application server's PATH;
        // EDIT THE FOLLOWING LINES
        $sms_user = "username"; // User Name (Provided by Inforu) ; $sms_user = "USERNAME";
        $sms_password = "password"; // Password (Provided by Inforu) ; $sms_password = "PASSWORD";
        $sms_sender = "my company"; // The SMS sender's (Optional, only English characters, 11 max. ); $sms_sender = "MyCompany";
        $message_text = str_replace (" ", "%20", $message_text); // Encodes spaces into "%20" in the URL;
        $query = 'InforuXML=' . urlencode('<Inforu><User><Username>'.
        $sms_user.'</Username><Password>'.
        $sms_password.'</Password></User><Content Type="sms"><Message>').
        $message_text.urlencode('</Message></Content><Recipients><PhoneNumber>'.
        $recepients.'</PhoneNumber></Recipients><Settings><Sender>'.
        $sms_sender.'</Sender><CustomerParameter>'.
        $customer_parameter.'</CustomerParameter></Settings></Inforu>');
        $fp = fsockopen("$sms_host", $sms_port, $errno, $errstr, 30); // Opens a socket to the Application server
        if (!$fp){ // Verifies that the socket has been opened and sending the message;
            echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
        } 
        else{
            $out = "GET $sms_path?$query HTTP/1.1\r\n";
            $out .= "Host: $sms_host\r\n";
            $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
            fwrite($fp, $out);
            while (!feof($fp)){
        echo fgets($fp, 128); // Echos the respond from application server (you may replace this line with an "Message has been sent" message);
        }
        fclose($fp);
        }
    }
?>
```

I check to code by adding to the url the variables, like
send-samir.php?date=date_vale&time="time_value with all the variables
and it work.

I can not seems to pass the variables, what I am doing wrong or missing?

I also added action="send-samir.php" to the form code thinking it help, but it do not help.
Do you need to form code also?

Comment: Can you do a `print_r($message)` before you call the `send_sms` function and let us know what it gets? If it doesn't print anything then you should also enable error reporting in PHP.

Comment: In your ajax call can you try set the `url` as an absolut path like starting with `/path/to/send-samir.php `

Comment: Where I going to see the message? I need to run the php file?
How I enable error reporting in PHP? I place the php on the root while the javascript file placed on the subdirectory, it is matter?

Comment: @caramba, the file is on the root

Comment: @hanan-mstudio then mark is as such `url: '/send-samir.php',`

Comment: google wordpress ajax and read up on it, don't forget wp implements a controller file and you need to allow access to specific files if needed.

Comment: @David, can you direct me ?

Comment: @apokryfos, I ran the php itself and got on the message what I sent

Comment: If you're using chrome, press F12 then in the window that opens click on "network". When you send the AJAX request you should see the activity in that tab along with request and response contents.

Comment: @apokryfos, thanks for the explanation. I not sure what I getting. I have the page name with the right path (send-samir.php), method (post), status (200) type (xhr).

I have error saying "js?v=3.exp:34 Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError" on the console window, can this cause problems? I do not use google maps.

Comment: I made some change in the code, how I post code on comments?

Comment: I used echo on the php file and alert on the javascript file.
I used echo $query and alert(result);
the new javascript is:
`$.ajax({
  url: '/send-samir.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {training:get_training,date:get_date,time:get_time,phone:get_phone},
  success: function(result) {
  //success
  alert(result);
  },
  error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
  console.log(xhr);
  console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
  }
  }); // end ajax call`

Comment: (this is continue of previous comment)
I got on the alert the query in encode form, so I think the call to the function is working and the parameter are passed, but nothing is happening.
I need to send parameters like on the code or I need to send the parameter name with apostrophe or something else?
There is a problem with the code using to send the message?